# JSON ответ, знаки вопросов вместо русских символов

Tags: android, json

Для чтения JSON и вывода инфы использую 2 класса

```
public class HttpHandler {

    //используем этот класс для получения json из url
    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();}}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url = "http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1";
    TextView jokeText;
    String joke;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        jokeText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.joke);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating new JSON Parser
            //  JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            HttpHandler jParser =new HttpHandler();
            String jsonStr = jParser.makeServiceCall(url);
            // Getting JSON from URL
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    joke=jsonObj.getString("content");

                }catch (final JSONException e) {

                }
            }
            return null;}

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            jokeText.setText(joke);

        }
    }
}
```

C английскими символами всё ок, а вместо русских знаки вопросов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Помогло, только установил кодировку cp1251, а не UTF-8